# No puedo leer DataReader con el método Read() C#/SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, stored-procedure, sql-server-2014

Estoy trabajando en C# y SQL Server 2014.
Necesito leer los datos que me está trayendo el DataReader de la base de datos. Según la propiedad `HasRows` el DataReader tiene registros pero al usar el método `Read()` para leerlos, el valor que devuelve Read() es `false`.

```
public static BindingList<Cuenta> MostrarCuentas(int pIdSistema, int pIdEntidad, int pIdCartera, bool pTelResidencial, bool pTelLaboral, bool pCelPrivado, bool pCelLaboral, bool pFavorito)
    {   
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BGSRVDS01;Initial Catalog=ModuloDePlanificacion;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        cmd.CommandText = "sp_MostrarCuentas";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pIdSistema", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pIdSistema;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pIdEntidad", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pIdEntidad;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pIdCartera", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pIdCartera;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pTelefonoResidencial", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = pTelResidencial;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pTelefonoLaboral", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = pTelLaboral;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pCelularPrivado", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = pCelPrivado;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pCelularLaboral", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = pCelLaboral;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pFavorito", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = pFavorito;

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        try
        {
            BindingList<Cuenta> Cuentas = new BindingList<Cuenta>();

            while (dr.Read() && dr.HasRows) //--> necesito ingresar a este while, pero el Read() devuelve 'false'.
            {

               //Acá voy agarrando los datos que trae 'dr' y creo un objeto 'Cuenta'  
               //con el que voy armando un lista de Cuentas  

            }
            con.Close();
            return Cuentas;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }    
    }
```

Los parámetros los recibe correctamente y el stored procedure se ejecuta normalmente.

Comment: Es posible que el procedimiento almacenado devuelva una sola fila?

Comment: No, devuelve varias

Comment: Por que usas HasRows y Read al mismo tiempo? Read debería hacer todo el trabajo

Comment: Cambia `while(dr.Read() && dr.HasRows)` por `while(dr.Read())` y dinos que pasa.

Comment: Gracias! con solo usar el Read() funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza solo `Read()` y no `HasRows`:

```
while(reader.Read()
{
  //...
}
```

Esto debido a que HasRows toma en cuenta otras condiciones para retornar true mientras que `Read()` verifica puntualmente si hay data disponible

Comment: Podrias explicar que toma en cuenta `HasRows` que puede provocar el comportamiento detectado por el OP?

Comment: @Pikoh Decir exactamente cuales no me es posible actualmente. pero si miras el [codigo fuente del `HasRows`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs#L175) notaras como se vale de una variable `_hasRows `. Esto quiere decir que la variable es modificada por otros metodos lo que indica que el estado de HasRow esta en base a otros. Mientras que [`Read()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs#L3116) no, `Read` depende del comportamiento de el mismo

Comment: Bueno...segun la documentación no hay ningun condicionante. HasRows devuelve true si el DataReader tiene una o mas columnas, y false en caso contrario. Por eso quería saber si tenías alguna información que yo no conociese.